# If selenium python sees a text closes driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make selenium close a tab after it spots a text saying 'Universal Script'

Right now I have this but it doesn't seem to work

```
is_universal = None
if title == "Universal Script":
    is_universal = True
if is_universal == None:
   ''rest of the code''
driver.close()
```

Code for the text

```
title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span').text
```

Comment: Do you mean that the tab stays open?

Comment: @DanGetz no it closes

I have a code that takes many links and when it closes it just goes to the next link

Comment: OK, so what does "it doesn't seem to work" mean, then?

Comment: @DanGetz it doesn't close the driver, just keeps going through the rest of the code

Comment: Well, first step of debugging this would be to print out what the value of `title` is and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @DanGetz Thank you very much. In the code I had it written as "Universal Script" but it actually was "Universal Script "